# Query-replace stops after first item in while

Tags: conditionals, iteration

Following [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58974551/how-to-iterate-through-a-list-of-literals-in-emacs-lisp/58975203#58975203), I coded this function to clean up text pasted from other sources, such as Google Docs:

```el
(defun sanitize-md ()
  "Replace characters."
  (interactive "*")
  (save-excursion
    (let ((replacement-list '(
                              ("\\" . "/")
                              ("ﬁ" . "fi")
                              ("“" . "\"")
                              ("”" . "\"")
                              )))
      (while (let* ((pair (pop replacement-list))
                    (to-find (car pair))
                    (to-replace (cdr pair)))
               (message "%s %s" to-find to-replace)
               (query-replace to-find to-replace nil (point-min) (point-max))
               )
        replacement-list)
      )))
```

My problem is the curly double quote `“`, which I have in a document. When I run this function, I get this in the `*Messages*` buffer:

```
\ /
Mark set
Replaced 0 occurrences
```

If I remove the line on `query-replace`, then the `*Messages*` buffer shows all four pairs. And if I put the double-quote pair as the first element of the list, then it gets replaced.

Why does `query-replace` stop at the first element of the `dolist`, and how can I code the replacement of all pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to match the form `(while COND BODY)` to what you have above, you will see that COND matches

```el
(let* ((pair (pop replacement-list))
       (to-find (car pair))
       (to-replace (cdr pair)))
       (message "%s %s" to-find to-replace)
       (query-replace to-find to-replace nil (point-min) (point-max))
)
```

and BODY is just `replacement-list`. The `while` evaluates the `COND` and loops as long as its value is `t`. But in this case the value of the `COND` is the value of the last form in the `let*`, i.e. the value of `(query-replace ...)`: since that does not find anything to replace with the first pair, it returns `nil` - so the value of the `COND` is `nil` and the `while` is done.

It may be that you have misplaced some parentheses and you really meant to write this:

```el
      (while  (let* ((pair (pop replacement-list))
                     (to-find (car pair))
                     (to-replace (cdr pair)))
        (message "%s %s" to-find to-replace)
        (query-replace to-find to-replace nil (point-min) (point-max))
        replacement-list))
```

Comment: Yes, it was a bug in the original StackOverflow answer and I have now edited it too.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `while`, not `dolist`, `while` stops when the TEST condition returns nil, not sure about the value of `query-replace`, but it definitely does not do what you want.